# How can I store a value as global variable from an API response and pass it to another API as parameter in Cucumber feature file using REST assured

Tags: java, cucumber, api-testing, bdd, rest-assured

I am designing automation scripts using the Cucumber BDD framework for REST APIs using RestAssured. I have one API which generates the "Token" and then there is another API for order creation which requires this "Token" in the authorization parameter. Here is my feature file:

```
Feature: Create Order API

  @Background:
  Scenario Outline: Generate Access token With Valid Details
    Given Query param for request
      | grant_type         |
      | client_credentials |
    Given Basic Auth keys for request "<userName>" and "<key>"
    When Build request for baseurl "PAYPAL_BASE_URI" and endpoint "ENDPOINT_GET_AUTH_KEY"
#    And Set global "access_token" in "token"
    And Perform "POST" request using
    Then status code is 200
    And  response contains "scope"
    Examples:
      | userName    | key |                                                                  
   | AWnCbuv9Bee0_6 | EMWowD696LqfznidhQ2RT_jZL2ys |
```

Now the response of the above API is as follows:

```
{
    "scope": "https://uri.pppaypal.com/services/invoicing https://uri.pppaypal.com/services/applications/webhooks",
    "access_token": "ALs1szFnv2TJ19Zf3vq",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "app_id": "APP-284543T",
    "expires_in": 311286,
    "nonce": "2022-05-31T03:41:41ZWs9dpOQ"
}
```

Now I need this "access_token" as  in the "Create Order API" Authorization parameter with Bearer. The "Create Order API" feature file is below:

```
 Scenario: Verify create order api using valid auth
    Given Generate request
    And Build request for baseurl "PAYPAL_BASE_URI" and endpoint "ENDPOINT_CREATE_ORDER_API"
    And Set header values as
      | Content-Type     | Authorization                                                                                            |
      | application/json | Bearer <token> |
    When Perform "POST" request using "FILE_PATH_ORDER_JSON"
    Then status code is 201
```

How can I set "access_token" in "token" as a global variable from the feature file so that I can use it anywhere in this feature file using the following step?

```
And Set global "access_token" in "token"
```

Answer (score 1):

To set `access_token` as a global variable in Cucumber feature file using REST assured, you can follow these steps:

1 Create a class to store global variables:
Create a new class to store global variables and their values. This class should have a public static variable to store the value of the `access_token` as follows:

```
public class GlobalVariables {
public static String access_token;
}
```

2 Set the value of `access_token` as a global variable:
To set the value of `access_token` as a global variable, you can parse the response of the "Generate Access token With Valid Details" scenario and set the value of `access_token` to the global variable as follows:

```
@Given("^Query param for request$")
public void queryParamRequest(Map<String, String> queryParams) {
// Your code to set query params
}

@Given("^Basic Auth keys for request "([^"])" and "([^"])"$")
public void basicAuthKeysRequest(String userName, String key) {
// Your code to set basic auth keys
}

@When("^Build request for baseurl "([^"])" and endpoint "([^"])"$")
public void buildRequest(String baseUrl, String endpoint) {
// Your code to build request
}

@When("^Perform "([^"]*)" request using$")
public void performRequest(String method) {
// Your code to perform request
Response response = RestAssured.given().when().post();
GlobalVariables.access_token = response.jsonPath().getString(`access_token`);
}
```

3 Use the global variable in the "Create Order API" scenario:
To use the `access_token` global variable in the "Create Order API" scenario, you can replace the "" placeholder with the value of the global variable as follows:

```
@Given("^Generate request$")
public void generateRequest() {
// Your code to generate request
}

@Given("^Build request for baseurl "([^"])" and endpoint "([^"])"$")
public void buildRequest(String baseUrl, String endpoint) {
// Your code to build request
}

@Given("^Set header values as$")
public void setHeaderValues(Map<String, String> headers) {
// Your code to set header values
headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + GlobalVariables.access_token);
}

@When("^Perform "([^"])" request using "([^"])"$")
public void performRequest(String method, String filePath) {
// Your code to perform request
}
```

By following these steps, you can store the `access_token` value as a global variable and use it in any scenario in the feature file.

Answer (score 0):

The feature files are meant to be used for describing your [domain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/134420/256527), no low-level details of how your automation code works. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDD5EEJgpHU) from Dave Farley to see the separation from Domain and Implementation Details.

Now, back to the question, if you want to have a global state, you can simply have a [Singleton](https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton) that will hold this state.

```
public final class TokenState {

    private static TokenState INSTANCE;
    private String token;
    
    private TokenState() { }
    
    public static ClassSingleton getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new TokenState();
        }
        
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
       this.token = token;
    }

    public void getToken() {
       return this.token;
    }
}
```

This way, whenever you want to mutate the global token, you can simply do `TokenState.getInstance.setToken("blabla")` or to retrieve the token you do `TokenState.getInstance.getToken()`.

Note: If you prefer, you can use [lombok-pg](https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/wiki/%40Singleton) to simplify the implementation of the Singleton.